# Element is not visible after clicking on save button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In firefox browser if the UI page is long or lengthy,

And  if some actions (like SAVE,EDIT) is performed in the bottom part of the page the tab on the top get invisible.

Is anyone faced this type of issue in selenium web-driver ?

Comment: Can u share the screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we faced this issue several times. That time we can scroll the page  up to element becomes visible using javascript code.

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
```

}

check whether element is displayed or not, if not displayed scroll again

Answer (score 0):

You should scroll the page until the element in view.
With JS in Selenium Java projects it's done like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("elementId")); //change as you need
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

P.S. in your project, JS execution can be done differently.